# Como fazer pg_dump remotamente

Tags: postgresql, dump

Tenho um servidor na Amazon com espaço de armazenamento pequeno, preciso fazer o backup na minha maquina pessoal.

se eu entrar no servidor e rodar

```
pg_dump -h localhost bd > backup.sql
```

tudo funciona, porém o backup é de 700mb.

Comment: Não é melhor gerar o backup local (como você já faz) e depois transferir o arquivo para a sua máquina local por `sftp`?

Comment: resolveu seu problema @Herick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tendo o postgresql instalado na sua máquina (ou os arquivos necessários), você consegue executar o mesmo comando trocando o parâmetro `-h` pelo ip/domínio do seu servidor na Amazon.

Observando que, pode ter restrição de acesso direto ao banco, rotas, firewall, etc.

> Eu, faria o backup lá no servidor, compactaria (com proteção), e enviaria para onde eu precisar. O dump compactado certamente ficará muito menor, e ainda terá proteção, uma vez que é texto puro.
>
> Para testar, peguei um dump de 2,39 GB (2.574.549.841 bytes) e compactei, utilizando o winRar e método de compressão ótimo. O resultado foi um arquivo de 845 MB (886.901.867 bytes).